# How to convert sklearn linear regression coefficient and intercept to 3 decimals?

Tags: python-3.x

I ran a linear regression using sklearn LinearRegression.
I need to get the coefficient and intercept in three decimals

```
slm=LinearRegression()
slm.fit(X_train,y_train)
coefficient=slm.coef_
intercept=slm.intercept_
```

Note{X_train and y_train) are numpy array

I am getting the following output

array([-4.65752878])
166.36702166414491

I tried with the round function, but it shows an error message. I need to convert the output into three decimals like the following format
-4.65
166.36

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
print('Coefficient(s): ', (*['{0:0.3f}'.format(i) for i in coefficient]),sep='\n' )

print('Intercept:{0:0.3f}'.format(intercept))
```